# Assigning string chars from end to start

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I have been experimenting with various ways to operate on a string and
wrote the following code.

```cpp
std::string a = "abcde";
std::string b;
b.resize(a.length());

int times = a.length();
while (times > 0)
{
    b[times - 1] = a[b.length() - times];
    times--;
}
std::cout << b << '\n';

return 0;
```

The idea is to resize a string and then set single characters index by index. Now the code works,
but a few days back I was getting Segmentation fault (please note, I can't remember that the code was absolutely identical to this one).

The question is, is this a legitimate piece of code (let's say, when I want to fill in a string from end to start without using inserts and reverses)?

Comment: If code was exactly this, it _may_ cause issues with some not-quite-compliant compilers, e.g. old MSVC and if you used `printf` on `c_str()` instead of `std::cout`. Otherwise it's quite fine, but you could forget -1 and thus try to write at `end()` of string `b`.

Comment: Interesting side note: Because of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) it is possible to write programs that can visibly fail on one day and not the next without changing a single line of code. That doesn't seem to be the case with this example code. Even the length zero case is looked after. While the code could take better advantage of C++ Standard Library features, what you've got here looks solid. That said, the only way to be sure is via [formal proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof) or exhaustive testing.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look wrong, but it is very easy to get this sort of code wrong, and you have to read through it to work out what the intent is.

Hmm... generally the idea of containers is that you use the iterator notation.
Of course, they are also strings of characters, and sometimes you can't avoid doing indexing operations.

But for something like this, you can quickly reverse a string by using the insert method and reverse iterator range, or the iterator range constructor for example:

```
std::string b {a.rbegin(), a.rend()};
```

Lots of ways.

Answer (score 2):

Reversing strings can be done easier in C++

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string a = "abcde";
  std::string b;

  b.resize(a.length());
  std::copy(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), b.begin());

  std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

If `b` is a new variable and not an existing one to modify, then it can be initialized with the required reversed string value on the declaration line

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string a = "abcde";

  std::string b(a.rbegin(), a.rend());

  std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler to pass the reverse iterators directly to the string constructor instead: `std::string b(a.rbegin(), a.rend());`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason for segmentation fault in the code that you posted.

But there are several more elegant ways to reverse a string.
The best way is probably to use reverse iterators as shown in the other answers.

Another alternative is to use [**`std::reverse`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "abcde";
    std::string b = a;
    std::reverse(b.begin(), b.end());   // <---
    std::cout << a << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
abcde
edcba
```

The only drawback here is that in this scenario each character is actually copied twice (once in the initial assignment, and once during `std::reverse`).