# Most efficient way to move last n chars to another string

Tags: c++, string, memory-efficient

This is in a way related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814883/assigning-string-chars-from-end-to-start).

My task is to take last `times` characters of string `str` and add them to string `removed`, and to remove those characters from `str`.

My idea was to do one memory allocation, iterate over `times` characters of `str` one time. That's what I am doing in the code below, assigning to `removed` index by index and popping from `str` per
iteration.

```
int times = std::stoi(arg); // arg is const std::string &        
std::string removed;
removed.resize(times); 
while (times > 0)
{
    removed[times-1] = str.back();
    str.pop_back();
    --times;
}
```

Question: what is the most efficient (without excessive copying, iterating several times, etc.) and elegant way to do this?

Comment: Unrelated: Your questions will be much stronger if you provide complete functions and often stronger still if you provide a simple-but-complete program that runs the function. In this case there is some ambiguity about the initial values of `times` and `str` that you can easily resolve with a more-complete example.

Comment: Practical note: Most of the time you don't need the *most efficient* solution. *Efficient enough* to meet the project requirements is what you're typically being paid to achieve, and is almost always easier to attain.

Comment: @user4581301 Got you, but I want to know the most efficient way still.

Comment: You will have to spend some time benchmarking then. What is "most" efficient on one system may not be most efficient on another system. Also the size of you dataset may change what is more efficient.

Comment: A classic example is count down or count up. On some systems it is more efficient to arrange the iteration so that the loop termination compares against zero because it is a simpler and faster operation. But these days, the compiler knows that trick [and will quietly adjust the output code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) to take advantage of it on systems where count to zero is quicker even if you wrote code that counts up. Most of the time you should write the simplest possible code, turn on the optimizer, and trust the compiler to do the smart thing.

Comment: Compilers are, at least for the foreseeable future, written by humans, and humans  write compilers that more easily recognize the intent of and better optimize for simpler solutions that humans recognize. Yes, you can out-do the compiler, but it generally takes a lot of work and expertise, knowing exactly how a given the compiler will interpret a piece of code. That knowledge may or may not port to other compilers (or even different versions of the same compiler) and often the code winds up looking so arcane you might as well have written assembly.

Answer (score 4):

I would do some checking before hand to make sure `times <= str.size()` but as long as it is this can be done pretty simple using `append` and `erase` like

```
removed.append(str.end() - times, str.end()); // adds the end of str to removed
str.erase(str.end() - times, str.end()); // removes the end from str
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this particular case why would you check? The size of `removed` is dependent on `times`.
Edit: I think I get what you mean, `times` could be negative, so a check before modifying wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Synthwave09 Sorry, typo, fixed now.  I meant that you need to make sure `times` isn't larger than `str` is.

Comment: However. Doesn't using `append` and `erase` imply we are iterating two times?

Comment: @Synthwave09 Not really.  `append` will do one iteration but `erase` will see it erasing until the end so it will just move `end` to where `end - times` is.

Comment: @ted-lyngmo, yeah, because if `times` > `str.size()`, then once `str` is empty you will be getting segfaults on `.back()` and `.pop_back()`.

Comment: @Synthwave09 My previous, now removed, comment was about the `times < str.size()` condition which wouldn't allow for the whole `str` to be "moved" to `removed`.  It prevented segfaults just fine though, just as the current condition does.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use `substr` and `resize`:

```cpp
if(str.size() >= times) {
    std::string removed = str.substr(str.size() - times);
    str.resize(str.size() - times);
}
```

Then again, if you don't actually need the resulting strings to be mutable, a very efficient approach would be to create `std::string_view`s over the original `str` and leave `str` unchanged. `std::string_view`s are really cheap. They typically consist of only a pointer and a length and doesn't do any dynamic memory allocation. Note though that `str` must "outlive" the views since it's `str` that owns the actual memory.

```cpp
if(str.size() >= times) {
    std::string_view vStr(str.begin(), str.end() - times);
    std::string_view vRemoved(str.end() - times, str.end());
       
    std::cout << vStr << '\n';
    std::cout << vRemoved << '\n';
}
```